# numpy multiple slicing booleans

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having trouble editing values in a numpy array

```
import numpy as np
foo = np.ones(10,10,2)

foo[row_criteria, col_criteria, 0] += 5
foo[row_criteria,:,0][:,col_criteria] += 5
```

row_criteria and col_criteria are boolean arrays (1D). In the first case I get a

"shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape" error

In the second case, += 5 doesn't get applied at all. When I do

```
foo[row_criteria,:,0][:,col_criteria] + 5
```

I get a modified return value but modifying the value in place doesn't seem to work...

Can someone explain how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: foo is a 1D array, why are you trying to reference 3 dimensions?

Comment: sorry, that was a typo - will make a quick change to a 3D array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want:

```
foo[np.ix_(row_criteria, col_criteria, [0])] += 5
```

To understand how this works take this example:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.arange(25).reshape([5, 5])
print A[[0, 2, 4], [0, 2, 4]]
# [0, 12, 24]

# The above example gives the the elements A[0, 0], A[2, 2], A[4, 4]
# But what if I want the "outer product?" ie for [[0, 2, 4], [1, 3]] i want
# A[0, 1], A[0, 3], A[2, 1], A[2, 3], A[4, 1], A[4, 3]
print A[np.ix_([0, 2, 4], [1, 3])]
# [[ 1  3]
#  [11 13]
#  [21 23]]
```

The same thing works with boolean indexing. Also `np.ix_` doesn't do anything really amazing, it just reshapes it's arguments so they can be broadcast against each other:

```
i, j = np.ix_([0, 2, 4], [1, 3])
print i.shape
# (3, 1)
print j.shape
# (1, 2)
```

Comment: thanks. but how come boolean arrays don't return the same view I was expecting?

Comment: Because you're expecting the "outer product" type of view. The "outer product" view is probably the more useful one when you're talking about boolean indexing, but the default in numpy is element-wise indexing. Because numpy supports several types of indexing and broadcasting allows numpy to easily support "outer product" indexing with the `ix_` function, defaulting to element wise indexing seems like the reasonable choice. But reasonable or not, numpy defaults to element wise indexing.