# Follow up to: numpy multiple slicing booleans

Tags: python, numpy

This is a follow-up to [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598646/numpy-multiple-slicing-booleans)

```
import numpy as np
foo = np.ones(10,10,2)

foo[np.ix_(row_boolean,col_boolean,[1])] += bar[np.ix_(col_boolean)]
```

bar is a 1D array and row_boolean and col_boolean are 1D boolean arrays. I wanted to apply certain numbers from the 1D bar array to the corresponding columns in foo, for all row == True in row_boolean.

When I try to do the above (such that boolean_arr is all False), I get the following error:

> *** ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (0,0,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (0,0,0)

How do I fix the above? Seems like

```
foo[np.ix_(row_boolean,col_boolean,[1])].shape == (0,0,1)
bar[np.ix_(boolean_arr)].shape == (0,)
```

Thanks!

EDIT:
something to this effect, only that I have an extra third dimension

```
In [46]: foo = np.random.random([5,5])

In [47]: foo
Out[47]: 
array([[ 0.02736112,  0.71269725,  0.73994453,  0.21814789,  0.19557647],
       [ 0.82418806,  0.94340516,  0.51143188,  0.51030109,  0.30127457],
       [ 0.6996424 ,  0.44577645,  0.24166962,  0.49316502,  0.3283645 ],
       [ 0.94403   ,  0.64943989,  0.51634012,  0.78914121,  0.73034792],
       [ 0.16748087,  0.64182321,  0.50958472,  0.67246253,  0.17233392]])

In [48]: bar = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

In [49]: col_filter = bar > 2

In [50]: col_filter
Out[50]: array([False, False,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [51]: row_filter = foo[:,1] > .5

In [52]: row_filter
Out[52]: array([ True,  True, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [53]: foo[np.ix_(row_filter,col_filter)]
Out[53]: 
array([[ 0.73994453,  0.21814789,  0.19557647],
       [ 0.51143188,  0.51030109,  0.30127457],
       [ 0.51634012,  0.78914121,  0.73034792],
       [ 0.50958472,  0.67246253,  0.17233392]])

In [54]: foo[np.ix_(row_filter,col_filter)] += bar[np.ix_(col_filter)]

In [55]: foo
Out[55]: 
array([[ 0.02736112,  0.71269725,  3.73994453,  4.21814789,  5.19557647],
       [ 0.82418806,  0.94340516,  3.51143188,  4.51030109,  5.30127457],
       [ 0.6996424 ,  0.44577645,  0.24166962,  0.49316502,  0.3283645 ],
       [ 0.94403   ,  0.64943989,  3.51634012,  4.78914121,  5.73034792],
       [ 0.16748087,  0.64182321,  3.50958472,  4.67246253,  5.17233392]])
```

Comment: I think you need to explain better what you're trying to do.When you're doing `foo[np.ix_(row_boolean,col_boolean,[1])] += X` it seems like `X` should be a scaler or have shape (1,). What do you expect when `bar[np.ix_(boolean_arr)]` has shape (3,) for example?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have time to explain why, but you want

```
foo[np.ix_(row_boolean, col_boolean) + (1,)] += bar[col_boolean]
```

You can read more than you probably want to know about [advanced indexing here.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing)