# using np.ix_ to subset 2D array returns 3D array where the newest dimension is 1

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I am automating the import and plotting of data (in rows of columns, so a 2D array) from a test instrument.  My data after import has an index based on the specimen number in the first column of each row, and I want to select the data in other columns based on that index.  I found a question that is similar here [Select certain rows (condition met), but only some columns in Python/Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23911875/) and followed that example to get the correct subset.  What I don't understand is why the 2D array is returned as a 3D array, with one dimension of length 1.

Minimal working example:

```
>>> c = np.array([[1,1,6,7],[1,2,9,8],[2,3,4,3],[3,4,6,2]])
>>> c
array([[1, 1, 6, 7],
       [1, 2, 9, 8],
       [2, 3, 4, 3],
       [3, 4, 6, 2]])
>>> np.shape(c)
(4, 4)

>>> d = c[np.ix_(c[:,0] == 1),2:4]
>>> d
array([[[6, 7],
        [9, 8]]])
>>> np.shape(d)
(1, 2, 2)
```

I know that all I need to do to get my 2D array is `d[0]`, but I am trying to understand why it returns my data this way, as in, did I misunderstand what the code was supposed to be-it worked this time as a fluke, but another time it might fail?  Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not directly do `c[c[:,0] == 1, 2:4]`?

Comment: Because I only need the rows where the index is 1.

Comment: ...what I type does the same thing, or am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, actually, I missed where you did the Boolean.  I will have to try and see if that works for my real data (it is actually much more complex than my MWE).  Mostly, I was trying to understand the "why" of the extra dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down into palatable bits.

1) There are two fundamental kinds of indexing in `numpy`: fancy and non-fancy. Fancy is indexing with arrays and lists, non-fancy is with slices and Ellipsis, single number indices are a bit in-between.

2) When fancy indexing the output shape is mostly determined by the indexing array, and only to a lesser degree by the indexed array:

```
>>> a = np.arange(2, 12, 2)
>>> a
array([ 2,  4,  6,  8, 10])
>>> I = np.arange(4)
>>> I
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> a[I]
array([2, 4, 6, 8])
>>> I2 = I.reshape(2, 2)
>>> I2
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
>>> a[I2]
array([[2, 4],
       [6, 8]])
```

3) when fancy and non-fancy indexing are mixed they are applied independently:

```
>>> aa = np.add.outer(a, np.arange(0, 400, 100))
>>> aa
array([[  2, 102, 202, 302],
       [  4, 104, 204, 304],
       [  6, 106, 206, 306],
       [  8, 108, 208, 308],
       [ 10, 110, 210, 310]])
>>> aa[I, 2:4]
array([[202, 302],
       [204, 304],
       [206, 306],
       [208, 308]])
>>> aa[I2, 2:4]
array([[[202, 302],
        [204, 304]],

       [[206, 306],
        [208, 308]]])
```

by contrast:

```
>>> aa[I, I]
array([  2, 104, 206, 308])
```

4) `np.ix_` returns a tuple. This is interpreted as a singleton dimension:

```
>>> np.ix_(I)
(array([0, 1, 2, 3]),)
>>> aa[np.ix_(I), 2:4]
array([[[202, 302],
        [204, 304],
        [206, 306],
        [208, 308]]])
>>> aa[I[None], 2:4]
array([[[202, 302],
        [204, 304],
        [206, 306],
        [208, 308]]])
```

By an unfortunate or at least very confusing design choice in the indexing machinery, the tuple would be ignored if it was the only index:

```
>>> aa[np.ix_(I)]
array([[  2, 102, 202, 302],
       [  4, 104, 204, 304],
       [  6, 106, 206, 306],
       [  8, 108, 208, 308]])
>>> aa[I[None]]
array([[[  2, 102, 202, 302],
        [  4, 104, 204, 304],
        [  6, 106, 206, 306],
        [  8, 108, 208, 308]]])
```

Comment: Thank you, that was quite helpful. I will need to practice quite a bit more to understand numpy indexing.

Comment: @JOdell these are already quite advanced things. If you master them you can consider yourself a numpy guru ;-)