# How to return values in the second column greater than 25 from a random array in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array that looks like such:

```
import numpy as np

z=np.random.randint(101,size=(5,3))

array([[41, 98, 63],
       [61, 65, 66],
       [21,  3, 90],
       [53, 60, 26],
       [60, 18, 19]])
```

I want to return values in the second column greater than 25, such as my answer will be:

```
array([[98],
       [65],
       [60]])
```

I tried to create a condition as such:

```
condition = z[:,1:2] > 25
```

but when I tried to run:

```
 z[condition]
```

I get an **error**

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1:
>   FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional
>   indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`.
>   In the future this will be interpreted as an array index,
>   `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a
>   different result.
>
> """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 z[condition]
>
> IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension
>   1; dimension is 3 but the corresponding boolean dimension is 1

Can someone help, please?

Comment: Can you share some context for this? What kind of data is it, why is it in a NumPy array?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23911875/select-certain-rows-condition-met-but-only-some-columns-in-python-numpy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22927181/11301900

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455076/how-to-access-the-ith-column-of-a-numpy-multidimensional-array?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select certain rows (condition met), but only some columns in Python/Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23911875/select-certain-rows-condition-met-but-only-some-columns-in-python-numpy)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
z=np.random.randint(101,size=(5,3))
dfx = pd.DataFrame(data=z, columns='A B C'.split())
y = np.array(dfx.B[dfx.B>25]).reshape(len(dfx.B[dfx.B>25]),1)
print(y)
```

Comment: This solution is incredibly, ridiculously over-engineered. Having to use Pandas for this trivial operation is astounding. If `arr` is the NumPy array and `df` is the DataFrame created from that array, then the solution is simply `df.loc[df[1].gt(25), 1].to_numpy()`.

Comment: @AMC got an error running your solutions ''numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'loc'"

Comment: got:  array([58, 47]), the questioner wanted the output in different shape .....but I learnt from you inputs thnx, my code could have been little simpler @AMC

Comment: I would like some clarification from OP on the matter, actually. I don’t see any evidence that the shape of example output was a deliberate choice, it’s a small thing. In any case, adding the dimension should be trivial, either with indexing and `numpy.newaxis`, `numpy.reshape()`, or `numpy.expand_dims()`.

Comment: You also didn’t explain in your answer why that solution is better than the alternative(s).

Answer (score 3):

You should look at what `condition` is giving you:

```
> a[:,1:2] > 25
array([
   [ True],
   [ True],
   [False],
   [ True],
   [False]])
```

That's probably not the shape you want. If instead you make the condition:

```
> a[:,1] > 25
array([ True,  True, False,  True, False])
```

You get a one-dimensional array you can use to index the single column:

```
> condition = a[:,1] > 25
> a[:,1:2][condition]

array([
   [98],
   [65],
   [60]
])
```

If you just want a flat result you can the same mask:

```
> a[:,1][condition]

array([98, 65, 60])
```