# How to extract elements from a predict_proba() generated xgboost array with a greater than or equal to 90% probability of being classified as 1?

Tags: python, probability, xgboost, predict

How can I extract elements from an array generated by `opt.predict_proba(x_test)`?

I'm working on a classification model, where I would like to select the results in the array that have a probability of 90% or higher of being classified as 1. How can I do that?

[Result of prediction probabilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FooPT.png)

I tried to run the array and return values greater than `[0.9, 0.1]`. But it didn't work and I thought it really wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
a[:,0] >= 0.9
```

where `a` is the result from `opt.predict_proba(x_test)` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23911875/select-certain-rows-condition-met-but-only-some-columns-in-python-numpy)).

This extracts the first column then creates an array with True/False depending on whether each value is >=0.9. To get the indices of the matching rows, use [.nonzero()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html#numpy.nonzero). To get the rows themselves, use `a[a[:,0] >= 0.9]`.